# Is there Wordpress function to directly get another website?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to during creation of new page get possibility to write another website and redirect when click on it. But there is only option to make it internally. Thank you. Maybe should I check some files on FTP?

[image: Redirect my new page]

Answer (score 0):

You want to add link of another website to your website. If you wanna add link to navbar, then simply go to your webiste's

```
`wp-admin -> Appearence -> Menus`.
```

Now, click on the `Custom link` displaying in the pages list. It's simple
[image]